# Using select() in client/server acknowledgement in C

Tags: c, client-server

I'm developing in C a Unix application consisting of a server that has to communicate simultaneously with at most five clients. Clients send to server a command which can be `tuttomaiuscolo (alltoupper in english)` or `tuttominuscolo (alltolower)` and a string to manipulate; the server receives the two strings and remove from the second word all the characters that are not `a-z A-Z` characters. If a client sends the string `FINE (end)` the server has to stop and die (whitout leaving zombie processes).

The problem is the connection between the client and the server. To do this I've used the function `select` in server and in client too, but the problem is that the `select` placed in the server (that monitors the reading) doesn't see the client request, so it never goes to the `accept` function, while the client `select` (that monitors the writing) returns a value that means it is ready for writing.

Now I'll post the code:

`server:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void ripulisci (char* stringa);
void minuscola (char* orig, char* dest);
void maiuscola (char* orig, char* dest);
void handler(int);

int list;
int sock;

int main () {
    int status;

//creo un socket da mettere in ascolto
list = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (list < 0) {
    perror("Error!");
    exit(1);
}

//preparo la struct sockaddr_in
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons(2770);

//effettuo il bind
status = bind(list, (struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(address));
if (status < 0) {
    perror("Error!");
    close(list);
    exit(1);
}

//mi metto in ascolto
listen(list, 1);
printf("Attendo le connessioni...\n");

//preparo le variabili necessarie per gestire i figli
int esci = 1;
pid_t server[5];
char comando[15];
char lettura[512];
char scrittura[512];
struct sockaddr_in client;
int client_size = sizeof(client);
fd_set fd;
FD_ZERO(&fd);
FD_SET(list, &fd);
struct timeval timer;

//genero i quattro figli/server e mi salvo i pid in un array
int index;
for (index=0 ; index<5 ; index++) {
    server[index] = fork();
    if (server[index] == 0)
        break;
}

//verifico quale processo sono
if (index == 5) {
    pause(); //aspetto un segnale da uno dei figli
}

//sono un figlio/server
else {
    while(esci) {
        timer.tv_sec = 1;
        timer.tv_usec = 0;
        if (select(list+1, &fd, NULL, NULL, &timer) <= 0) {
            printf("Nessun client da servire\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (!FD_ISSET(list, &fd))
            continue;
        printf("C'è un client\n");
        sock = accept(list, (struct sockaddr*) &client, (socklen_t*) &client_size);
        if (sock < 0)
            break;
        printf("Connesso con il client\n");
        recv(sock, comando, 15, 0);
        recv(sock, lettura, 512, 0);
        if (comando[0] == 'F' && comando[1] == 'I' && comando[2] == 'N' && comando[3] == 'E' && comando[4] == '\0')
            kill(getppid(), SIGALRM); //al termine dell'esecuzione uscirò
        ripulisci(lettura);

        //il comando è tuttomaiuscole
        if (strcmp("tuttomaiuscolo", comando) == 0) {
            maiuscola(lettura, scrittura);
            send(sock, scrittura, 512, 0);
        }

        //il comando è tuttominuscole
        else if (strcmp("tuttominuscolo", comando) == 0) {
            minuscola(lettura, scrittura);
            send(sock, scrittura, 512, 0);
        }

        //c'è stato un errore
        else {
            printf ("Error! Command not found\n");
            strcpy (scrittura, "error");
            send (sock, scrittura, 512, 0);
        }
        printf("Devo terminare!");
        close(sock);
        exit(0);
    }
}

//termino tutto
for(index=0 ; index<5 ; index++) {
    waitpid((int)server[index], NULL, 0);
}
exit(0);
}

void handler(int sig) {
signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
printf("Il server sta terminando in seguito ad una richiesta\n");
close (list);
close (sock);
exit(0);
}

void ripulisci (char* stringa) {
int index = 0;
int app;
while (stringa[index] != '\0' && index<=511) {
    if (isalpha(stringa[index])!=1) {
        app = index;
        do {
            stringa[app] = stringa[app+1];
            app++;
        } while (stringa[app] != '\0');
        stringa[app] = '\0';
        index--;
    }
    index++;
}
return;
}

void minuscola (char* orig, char* dest) {
int index = 0;
do {
    if (orig[index] < 91)
        dest[index] = toupper(orig[index]);
    else
        dest[index] = orig[index];
    index++;
} while (orig[index] != '\0');
dest[index] = '\0';
return;
}

void maiuscola (char* orig, char* dest) {
int index = 0;
do {
    if (orig[index] > 91)
        dest[index] = tolower(orig[index]);
    else
        dest[index] = orig[index];
    index++;
} while (orig[index] != '\0');
dest[index] = '\0';
return;
}
```

`client:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main () {
int descrittoreSocket;
descrittoreSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(2770);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
printf ("Connessione in corso...\n");
int ris;
ris = connect(descrittoreSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &address, (socklen_t) sizeof(address));

fd_set fd;
FD_ZERO(&fd);
FD_SET(descrittoreSocket, &fd);
struct timeval timer;
timer.tv_sec = 1;
timer.tv_usec = 0;

if ((ris > -1) && select(descrittoreSocket+1, NULL, &fd, NULL, &timer) >= 0 && FD_ISSET(descrittoreSocket, &fd)) {
    printf ("Connessione avvenuta...\n");
    char buffer_r [512];
    char buffer_w [512];
    char command [15];
    gets(command);
    gets(buffer_r);
    send(descrittoreSocket, command, 15, 0);
    printf("Spedito!");
    fflush(stdout);
    send(descrittoreSocket, buffer_w, 512, 0);
    printf("Spedito!");
    fflush(stdout);
    recv(descrittoreSocket, buffer_r, 512, 0);
    printf("Trasferito!");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (strcmp("error", buffer_r) == 0)
        printf ("ERROR!");
    printf ("%s", buffer_r);
    fflush(stdout);
} else {
    printf ("Impossibile servire il client\n");
}
    close (descrittoreSocket);
    exit(0);
}
```

With syntax higligh:

server: http://pastebin.com/5Nd96JxC

client: http://pastebin.com/aSvR6qVM

Please don't hesitate to ask for clarifications if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server shouldn't need to use `select` with only one listening socket ... instead it should listen for a connection on the listening socket for a client, and when there's a connection, accept it, and then read from the socket the command given by the client.  If you want to process more than one request from a client at a time, then you can spin off a separate process or thread for each accepted connection.  If you want to avoid blocking behavior during the call to `accept` by the listening socket, then you can always use `ioctl` with the `FIONBIO` flag on the listening socket.

On the client side I also don't see a need for `select` ... again, there is only one socket on the server to talk to. Simply open a connection on the server, which will block until a connection is made, and when that connection is made, you can read and write to the server.

Comment: Actually you can call select() on a listening socket, and when it is readable - it means you have an incoming connection and you can call accept().

Comment: I wanted to use select() because, according to Asaf post, I don't want the server to block. As a matter of fact, if a don't use it and I call accept() the server while wait until when a client wants to connect to, and it can be good untile when a client doesn't write FINE (end). When it happens the father should signal to the children SIGUSR1, but the children are blocked, so I can't handle the event. In this case the server could turn off just at the next client-request, but if there are no more requests the server will never end. This is the hardest part...

Comment: I've red it's possibile using alse libevent.h to know when there is an incoming request on the server, anyone can explain or say me where I can found some documentation?

Comment: Thanks @Asaf for the correct on that point ... @litiales I still though don't see a need for `select` though if all you want is non-blocking behavior on your sockets ... that can be accomplished using `ioctrl` and the `FIONBIO` flag.  You only need `select` if you are working with multiple sockets, and you wanted to pick the active socket, but your code doesn't currently seem to be constructed to work that way.